# How to plan a logoff script inside a login script

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I am writing a login script in Powershell which install a amount of printers, depending on the user currently loggin into Windows 7.  I would like this user to remove the printers it have installed as soon as their are not required anymore, so as soon as this user log out.

How can I plan a script which will be executed as soon as the current sessions ends?

Thank for your time.

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a rabbit. SO can help with definite, discrete issues when presented with failing code - not with "how can I accomplish X". Especially when that question can be answered by simple Google search.

Comment: And my colleages do not think that this require only a simple google search...

Comment: Regardless of whether or not this question could be answered by a Google search, it remains an ifrastructure administration question and is thus off-topic for StackOverflow. [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) would be the right place to ask this, but you'd *still* need to show what you have tried so far, and explain how the results failed to meet your requirements.

Comment: Your limited vision of what is industrial and what is not begins to bother me.  But right I ask the question elsewhere...